# HandleChange Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with handleChange inputs in connection with Redux, it almost works, but not quite, because when I change state, in one field there is a change of state guess what I would like to achieve, but when I change in another field this state disappears from the first one and saves in the second one (on the picture below I showed what I mean). I have two such moderately convincing ideas, that is, in the reducer in the line "value: action.payload.num_building || '', and in the place of '' do ' ', so that there is always something there and then when I do the post I do the trim, so that there is no space, the post will fly as an empty value, or instead of '' do the state in the same place. num_building.value in one field and state.test.value in the other, but here the problem is that if I type something and then delete the whole input, there will always be the first letter of the text we typed and I don't know how to delete it :(

[image: Photo where state disappears]

**Slicer.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const numberBuildingSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'number_building',
  initialState: {
    num_building: { key: 'num_building', value: '' },
    test: { key: 'test', value: '' },
  },
  reducers: {
    inputChange: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        num_building: {
          ...state.num_building,
          value: action.payload.num_building || state.num_building.value,
        },
        test: {
          ...state.test,
          value: action.payload.test || ' ',
        },
      };
    },
  },
});

export const { inputChange } = numberBuildingSlice.actions;

export const numberBuildingState = (state) => state.number_building;

export default numberBuildingSlice.reducer;
```

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  numberBuildingState,
  inputChange,
} from '../redux/slices/numberBuildingSlice';
import LabelInput from '../reusable-components/LabelInput';

const URL = 'http://localhost:8000/numbers-buildings/';

function AddNumberBuilding() {
  const numberBuilding = useSelector(numberBuildingState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { value } = numberBuilding.num_building;

  const handleChange = async (event) => {
    const response = await dispatch(
      inputChange({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }),
    );
    console.log(response);
  };

  function postNumberBuilding() {
    const jsonData = { num_building: value };
    axios
      .post(URL, jsonData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error.response));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="num_building"
        onChange={handleChange}
        {...numberBuilding.num_building}
      />
      <input name="test" onChange={handleChange} {...numberBuilding.test} />
      <input type="submit" onClick={postNumberBuilding} value="Add New!" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddNumberBuilding;
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use the spread pattern. Redux Toolkit uses https://github.com/immerjs/immer which creates a proxy of the state object. 

You can simply do this: 

`state.num_building.value = action.payload.num_building || state.num_building.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating both the values in reducer, even though you are just sending one variable to be updated in dispatched function.

The solution is to use dynamic key accessor

```
reducers: {
    inputChange: (state, action) => {
      const key = Object.keys(action.payload)[0];
      return {
        ...state,
        [key ]: {
          ...state[action.payload[key]],
          value: action.payload[key ] || state.num_building.value,
        },
      };
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In your first version something doesn't work, when I something write in input Redux state doesn't get change, but second version is working! Thank you so much one more time!